# Installing Documentation fails

Tags: core-plot

I followed the instructions for installing the documentation from the source build (by compiling the documentation scheme in CorePlotExamples) but it fails when trying to compile the documentation with the following errors.

```
    3068: protocol_c_p_t_bar_plot_data_source-p.html
3069: protocol_c_p_t_scatter_plot_data_source-p.html
3070: _c_p_t_utilities_8m.html#a794f89cd14d4cfb21bf8c050b2df8237
3071: category_c_p_t_layer_07_c_p_t_platform_specific_layer_extensions_08.html
3072: interface_c_p_t_line_style.html#a4013bcb6c2e1af2e37cfabd7d8222320
3073: _c_p_t_utilities_8h.html#ae826ae8e3f55a0aa794ac2e699254cad
Loading symbols from /Users/GeoffCoopeMP/Downloads/core-plot-master-3/framework/CorePlotDocs.docset/html/com.CorePlot.Framework.docset/Contents/Resources/Tokens.xml
     1000 tokens processed...
     2000 tokens processed...**strong text**
     3000 tokens processed...
     4000 tokens processed...
     5000 tokens processed...
 *   5145 tokens processed (   1.8 sec)
 *     20 tokens ignored
Linking up related token references
Sorting tokens
rm -f com.CorePlot.Framework.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/Nodes.xml
rm -f com.CorePlot.Framework.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/Info.plist
rm -f com.CorePlot.Framework.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/Makefile
rm -f com.CorePlot.Framework.docset/Contents/Resources/Nodes.xml
rm -f com.CorePlot.Framework.docset/Contents/Resources/Tokens.xml
mkdir -p ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets
cp -R com.CorePlot.Framework.docset ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets
cp: /Users/GeoffCoopeMP/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/com.CorePlot.Framework.docset: Not a directory
make: *** [install] Error 1
find: /Users/GeoffCoopeMP/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/com.CorePlot.Framework.docset/Contents/: Not a directory
false
Showing first 200 notices only
Command /bin/sh emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure
```

I found the com.CorePlot.Framework.docset files (7kb) but noticed the KIND is "Unix executable file" rather than the expected "Documention Set" like other Xcode help files.

The dockset files are also 7kb in the zip file download under the documentation folder and the kind is shown as Unix executable file there too.

Under my user Library folder I can see the dockets as in:
[image: User Library folder]

I also noticed that the docksets can be within the Xcode.app contents but placing these files here didn't work either.

So, is this 7k file the right one?  should it be kind Documentation Set rather than Unix Exectuable File?  Why does the documentation not compile in Xcode but still generates the files?

I am using Xcode version 5.1.1, Doxygen 1.8.7, graphviz 2.36 and Core Plot 2.0 source from github.

Any help would be much appreciated as I am trying to learn how to use this excellent SDK.

Answer (score 1):

The Core Plot docsets should each be around 70 MB in size. A "docset" is a package which is a special type of folder treated as a single file in the Finder. When building Core Plot documentation, Doxygen makes the docset folder inside the Core Plot "framework" folder and copies it to your library from there.

Did the docset get built in the "framework" folder? Are there any aliases or file links in the path to the Core Plot folder that might be confusing Doxygen or the `cp` command?

Comment: Ok, just downloaded from github again.

1. Opened CorePlot.xcodeproj file in core-plot-master/frameworks/ folder
2. Selected Documentation schema in Xcode and hit run

I noticed that a coreplotdocs.docset file (137 MB) appeared in the frameworks folder while it was building then it deleted it and a com.CorePlot.Framework.docset file appeared at 7kb along with the same Xcode errors.

Comment: Also:

Warning: Tag `XML_SCHEMA' at line 1841 of file `/Users/GeoffCoopeMP/Documents/Projects/Rev/core-plot-master/framework/../documentation/doxygen/doxygen.config' has become obsolete.

Warning: Tag `XML_DTD' at line 1847 of file `/Users/GeoffCoopeMP/Documents/Projects/Rev/core-plot-master/framework/../documentation/doxygen/doxygen.config' has become obsolete.